# Message body empty in contact form (using PhPMailer)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm having a little problem with my contact form.

I'm using PhpMailer and Bootstrap contact form. When I run the code I get this message:

```
"Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Message body empty'"
```

This is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['InputName'];
$company = $_POST['InputFirma'];
$email = $_POST['InputEmail'];
$phone = $_POST['InputPhone'];
$message = $_POST['InputSubject'];

require '../../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require '../../PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;             // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'poczta.cgsa.com.pl';   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'sample@sample.pl'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'FU86m6BSp7';       // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('sample@sample.pl', 'Giełd');
$mail->addAddress('sample@sample.pl', 'Odbiorca'); // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                               // Set email format to HTML


if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Wiadomość nie mogła zostać wysłana';
    echo "<br><br><br><hr><br>";
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana';
}

$Body = "Wiadomość od: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Firma: $company\n";

$success = mail($name, $company, $phone, $message);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form class="padding-top-40" role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName">Imię i nazwisko</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" name="fullname"  placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" required data-error="Proszę wpisać swoje imię i nazwisko">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputFirma">Firma</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFirma" name="subject" name="comments"  placeholder="Firma" required data-error="Proszę wpisać nazwę firmy">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="emailid"  placeholder="E-mail" required data-error="Proszę wpisać swój email">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputPhone">Telefon kontaktowy</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="InputPhone" placeholder="Numer telefonu" required data-error="Proszę wprowadzić numer telefonu">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputSubject">Temat</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"  id="InputSubject" placeholder="Treść wiadomości" rows="4" required data-error="Proszę wpisać treść wiadomości"></textarea>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="padding-top-20">
    <button type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" >Wyślij</button>
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Question**

How can I address the error message?

Comment: You nowhere set message for PHPMAILER.... the funny is, that at the end you try to send mail again with standard mail() functions - there you even set message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just doing things in the wrong order. You need to set the `Body` property (and not just a variable called `$Body`) *before* you send the message, and you don't need to call `mail()` at all.

```
$mail->Body = "Wiadomość od: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Firma: $company\n";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Wiadomość nie mogła zostać wysłana';
    echo "<br><br><br><hr><br>";
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana';
}
```

You're using the auoloader, so you don't need to `require` the SMTP class separately, it will be loaded automatically.

You are enabling exceptions (by passing `true` in the constructor), but you are not wrapping your code in a try/catch block to deal with any that may happen.

Comment: There were no wrong order in his code. He didn't set body at all ;)